# Firefox : DOM Mutation Events for disconnected nodes?

Tags: firefox, mutation-events

I have a few questions (I am interested in answers related to Firefox, but answers in context of other browser might be acceptable too).

1. Do DOM Mutation events get fired for nodes disconnected from the main document, i.e. are disconnected? As per information present in one of the Mozilla bugs, the answer seems yes. Can someone give me some examples?
2. What is the quickest way of finding if a node is disconnected or not? The naive approach is walk (using node.parentNode) all the way up till we reach null or the document. Anything faster?
3. Does Firefox support Webkit's 'magic iframe' feature? If not, what will happen if that code ran in Firefox?
4. Related to #3, is it possible for a iframe to continue loading while disconnected from the document? I.e. it was connected to a main doc, loading started, then moved to another document (using adoptNode()), but never added to a parent node in the new doc. Will iframe continue loading?

Thanks in advance,
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `DOMNodeRemoved` event is fired when an a node (element, text node, comment, ..) is removed from the document/element to which the event is bound.

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
       console.log('Removed node: ' + event.target.nodeName);
   });
   ```
2. Benchmarking two possibilities:

   - A plain loop:

     ```
     function isDisconnected(node) {
         var rootElement = document.documentElement;
         while (node) {
             if (node === rootElement)
                 return false;
             node = node.parentNode;
         }
         return true;
     }
     ```
   - [`document.contains( node )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.contains):

     ```
     function isDisconnected(node) {
         return !document.contains(node);
     }
     ```

   Result: http://jsperf.com/dom-contains-vs-parentnode
   The [`document.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.contains) method significantly (47x) faster than the loop method (whether the nodes are disconnected or not, the `document.contains` method always outperforms the loop).
3. The Magic iframe feature does **not** work in Firefox, as tested using this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRFsd/
   For those who don't know about this feature: In Chrome, an iframe can be **moved** from one document to the other, without unloading the frame. This is called the [magic iframe](http://cananian.livejournal.com/60624.html) feature.

The provided [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GRFsd/) moves an iframe whose `src` attribute is set to `"data:text/html,<script>alert(/Test/);<\/script>"`. When this URL is loaded, an alert shows up. **Two** alerts showing up means that the Magic iframe feature **is not supported**. **One** alert showing up means that the feature **is supported**. Zero alerts showing up means that your JavaScript is disabled, or that your browser doesn't support data-URIs.

Comment: Note that WebKit removed the "magic iframe" feature a few days ago; they ran into too many security problems with it.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the answer. Regarding #1, I am not able to get a DOMNodeRemoved event fired when the parentNode isn't connected to the DOM. It does fire if parentNode is connected. Can you please give me some examples?

Comment: (Please ignore previous comment, I got the answer). Thanks Rob and Boris for the answers. Boris provided additional info on #1 above in another thread : 'Any mutation to disconnected nodes will fire mutation events.  You just have to have the listeners somewhere on the nodes' parent chain'. I tested and it works as Boris described.